Spring boot doesn't work for search by text when adding % inside the string
i am struggling with springboot. In my repository i search for products in the database where the name contains multiple words (for example i want to display "wet cat food" when i search by the terms "wet food"
Whenever i try to run the code i get nothing returned, even thou i have data in the database
    public ResponseEntity<?> getProductByName(String name) {
        ResponseEntity<?> response = null;
        String searchValue =name.replaceAll(" ", "%");

        System.out.println(searchValue);

        List<Product> productList = productRepository.findProductsByNameContainingIgnoreCase(searchValue);

        if(productList.isEmpty()){
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(productList, HttpStatus.OK);
        }

        return response;
    }

from all the testing i have done the culprit is the '%' character, but this shouldn't be the case because i am working with postgresql and % is wildcard in there...
If i write the sql instruction in postgresql it works, but the one from springboot doesn't work

% is a wildcard only if you use like, ilike, similar to, !~~, !~~*, ~~ or ~~*. You probably also need to add a % before and after the searchValue, to match cases where there's stuff not only between the phrases, but also before or after. You can also check if the db doesn't get the % escaped somehow and try to find how to prevent that. Keep in mind that you're forcing the search to also match the order of these phrases, so food cat and food wet won't match wet cat food.

@Zegarek This is what hibernate logs into console when i run the get request
select
    p1_0.id,
    p1_0.category,
    p1_0.name,
    p1_0.price,
    p1_0.quantity,
    p1_0.type 
from
    products p1_0 
where
    upper(p1_0.name) like upper(?) escape '\'

springboot adds automatically a % before and after the value i am searching for
Edit: If i try to add manually % before and after the searchvalue it will result in nothing even if i search for only one word, meanwhile the current implementation works with only one word

The key is in what the db gets in place of the ? placeholder, so try to inspect the query from the db end: my bet is that it arrives with the % characters you added, automatically escaped.

When you use the generated repository functions, using 'Containing' in the name triggers adding the '%' signs at start and end and escaping the '%' in the search string, so you are searching a long word containing '%'-signs.
